# Perl script cannot access Tabix folder

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, vcftools

I'm running a Perl script from the EMBL (found here https://github.com/EMBL-EBI-GCA/reseqtrack/blob/master/scripts/variation_data/calculate_allele_frq_from_vcf.pl) Under Ubuntu 16.10 I have installed Vcftools and Tabix as is required and both have been tested to work accordingly. I execute the script with the following command:

```
perl /home/[user]/calculate_allele_frq_from_vcf.pl \
-vcf /home/[user]/share/1000genomesPhase3VCFFiles/ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz \
-sample_panel /home/[user]/share/1000genomesPhase3VCFFiles/integrated_call_samples_v3.20130502.ALL.panel \
-out_dir /home/[user]/Desktop/AlleleFrequency \
-tabix  /home/[user]/tabix-0.2.6 \
-vcftools_dir /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13 \
-region 1:1-10000 \
-pop CEU,FIN \
```

This returns the following error

```
Smartmatch is experimental at /home/[user]/calculate_allele_frq_from_vcf.pl line 133.
Smartmatch is experimental at /home/[user]/calculate_allele_frq_from_vcf.pl line 144.
sh: 1: /home/[user]/tabix-0.2.6: Permission denied
Broken VCF header, no column names?
 at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 172.
    Vcf::throw(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55761601d320), "Broken VCF header, no column names?") called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 866
    VcfReader::_read_column_names(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55761601d320)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 601
    VcfReader::parse_header(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55761601d320)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/vcf-subset line 121
    main::vcf_subset(HASH(0x557615b24558)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/vcf-subset line 12
Broken VCF header, no column names?
 at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 172.
    Vcf::throw(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55fa53436f60), "Broken VCF header, no column names?") called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 866
    VcfReader::_read_column_names(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55fa53436f60)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 601
    VcfReader::parse_header(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x55fa53436f60)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/fill-an-ac line 45
    main::fill_an_ac(undef) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/fill-an-ac line 9
sh: 1: /home/[user]/tabix-0.2.6: Permission denied
Broken VCF header, no column names?
 at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 172.
    Vcf::throw(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x5607d059a190), "Broken VCF header, no column names?") called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 866
    VcfReader::_read_column_names(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x5607d059a190)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 601
    VcfReader::parse_header(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x5607d059a190)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/vcf-subset line 121
    main::vcf_subset(HASH(0x5607d00a1558)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/vcf-subset line 12
Broken VCF header, no column names?
 at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 172.
    Vcf::throw(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x556b8e952110), "Broken VCF header, no column names?") called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 866
    VcfReader::_read_column_names(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x556b8e952110)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/Vcf.pm line 601
    VcfReader::parse_header(Vcf4_2=HASH(0x556b8e952110)) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/fill-an-ac line 45
    main::fill_an_ac(undef) called at /home/[user]/vcftools_0.1.13/perl/fill-an-ac line 9
/home/[user]/Desktop/AlleleFrequency/calculated_fra.process3085.1.1-10000.CEU_FIN
```

It appears that the script doesn't have permission to access Tabix for some reason. I've given the folder full read/write permission for the user executing the script (me). Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but you should probably let the script's author know about `Smartmatch is experimental at ...` warnings. If the script is still being maintained, the author would probably want to know that it would be wise to address this warning by finding an alternative construct that avoids `~~`.

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1182443).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `-tabix` to `/home/[user]/tabix-0.2.6`, but the code seems to need the path to the executable, not the top directory. Adding `/bin/tabix` to the path should probably fix the problem.

Comment: Good call. I think you should post this over at PM as well. ...nevermind, I see you linked to it.

Comment: Thanks choroba, your answer is correct, except for the /bin/ part, The tabix executable is located in the base folder. Hence the correct path is `/home/[user]/tabix-0.2.6/tabix)`